# Is it SEO safe to put <span> inside <a> element?

Tags: seo, html

I am using DevExpress to create my site's main navigation menu, which is important to me to have Google crawl them but DevExpress Menu Control's output is not pure anchor element but rather an with a inside it.

Now is it SEO safe to use this menu? Here is the output code:

```
<li id="ASPxNavBar1_I0i0_" class="dxnb-item" onclick="ASPx.NBIClick(event, 'ASPxNavBar1', 0, 0)" style="text-align:Right;">

<a id="ASPxNavBar1_I0i0_T" class="dxnb-link" href="view.aspx?id=001"><span class="dx-vam">Some Link</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The span element doesn't have any semantic meaning, it is used to hook text within inline elements.

Using a span won't effect you from an SEO stand point.

Comment: Yes you can, elements such as <strong> <em> etc has an impact but not <span>

Comment: Invest some time in learning about the semantic of html. You'll worry less about seo.

Comment: im kind of freshman to seo world. thanks i'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @GrapeSoda one more thing! I trust you on this, should we not?!!

Comment: Should you not what?